# How do EBCDIC to ASCII / UTF-8 conversion using Perl by imitating Oracle SQL load?

Tags: oracle, perl, encoding, utf-8, encode

Usually, I use Oracle SQL developer to load EBCDIC data using ZHT16DBCS (Traditional Multi byte Chinese).

I don't know if I am asking the right question but I'm trying to imitate conversion of EBCDIC data into readable text using Perl v5.8.8. I have been successful so far by using the Encode and Convert modules in Perl but I am not sure if the multi-byte Chinese gets destroyed in the conversion because of the unsupported code page.

I've read that ZHT16DBCS uses code page 937.
Found here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b16217/a_nls.htm

But cp937 is not supported in  Perl Encode and Convert module

```
@all_encodings = Encode->encodings(":all");
```

Is it possible to imitate cp937 conversion using perl? I would like to check if the output I generate in Perl will have the same data that I loaded

```
SELECT * from EBCDIC_DATA_TABLE
```

Thanks

[EDIT]
Maybe I should rephrase this. How hard is it to create a EBCDIC CP937 to UTF-8 Conversion table? Thanks :)

Comment: *"I am not sure if the multi-byte Chinese gets destroyed in the conversion because of the unsupported code page"* Are you saying you don't know whether it gets destroyed (you should find out!) or that it gets destroyed but you don't know whether it's because of the unsupported code page.

Comment: Perl version 5.8.8 is over a decade old. Lots and lots of work on character encodings, including EBCDIC, have happened since. I strongly recommend that you get a less ancient Perl version.

Comment: @Bordodin Sorry I can't tell. I know nothing about chinese characters in EBCDIC data and my environment can't display them.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl I would like to but sorry I'm just working with what I have at the moment.

Comment: Can't you get Oracle to convert the data to UTF-8 for you? With MySQL, all you have to do is set the connection's encoding to UTF-8, and the DB will automatically convert everything to UTF-8 for you.

Comment: @ikegami yes but I'm trying to do it manually with perl.

Like:
EBCDIC data > Perl > ASCII / UTF-8

provided I still preserve the correct chinese data

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at the [`Text::Iconv`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Iconv) module, which is likely to be more comprehensive than `Encode`

I can't say for sure whether your `libiconv` will support code page 937, as it will depend on what is supplied with your system, bur running `iconv --list` on the command line will give you a good idea

Instead of using the module, you may prefer to open the file  piped through the `iconv` utility like this

```
open my $fh, '-|:encoding(utf-8)', qw/ iconv -f CP937 -t UTF-8 my_ebcdic_file / or die $!;
```

Then you can read decoded lines from the file in the usual way with `<$fh>`

Comment: Thanks @Borodin sorry got kind of busy lately but going back I have checked and its not supported. So it means that I can't use Text::Iconv since 937 is not supported correct?

iconv -l

Is it possible to install this manually?